# What is wrong in this code its not showing graph

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/dist/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green","Purple","Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)','rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)','rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)','rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)','rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)','rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>


<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>


                <div class="panel-body">

                    <canvas id="mycanvas" height="280" width="600"></canvas>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

i am getting nothing from this code its not showing chart i am using chartjs
anyone tell me whats wrong i am doing here i am using it on larave 5.2 if any one suggest how to do it on laravel 5.2 i really appreciate it please someone help

Answer (score 0):

As of now the code is executed with page content be loaded in DOM. You need to wait for DOM to build. You should use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    //Your code
});
```

Additionally, *github* is not a CDN thus don't refer to JavaScript file stored there directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still not showing any graph on the page

Comment: @FarhanJameelAhmed Start debugging and share error. The JS file is giving 404 [Not found ], point to correct url, see [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nnnick/Chart.js/master/dist/Chart.bundle.js

Gives 404 not found error. Please use your servers or a CDN to serve this file.

Answer (score 0):

check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rokc296k/)

you need to use a working cdn like: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.js

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>


        <div class="panel-body">

          <canvas id="mycanvas" height="280" width="600"></canvas>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

**JS**

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)', 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/oLyLt7Le/1/)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red","Blue","Yellow","Green","Purple","Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)','rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)','rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)','rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)','rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)','rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>


                <div class="panel-body">

                    <canvas id="mycanvas" height="280" width="600"></canvas>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```